# Redirect subfolder to root domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect the subfolder and allcontents to root domain.

For example:

http://www.example.com/ubb/ will redirect to http://www.example.com

I put the .htaccess on ubb folder and the code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [R=302,L]
```

However when you access http://www.example.com/ubb/threads.php it will redirect to http://www.example.com/threads.php it should be http://www.example.com

Is there any code to try or other possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this rule in `/ubb/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ubb/

RewriteRule ^ /? [R=302,L]
```

Also test it out in a different browser to avoid existing browser caches.

Answer (score 1):

It's achievable using PHP which will be quiet easier I believe.

Create `index.php` inside `ubb` folder & add this code to it.

**index.php**

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
?>
```

It'll redirect all request coming to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).