# nginx Redirect subfolder to root domain

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I want to redirect the subfolder and all contents to root domain.

For example:

http://www.example.com/ubb/ will redirect to http://www.example.com

My server configuration is like below:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /home/vishant/devcenter/wava-v1.1/HTML;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name baetter.l;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            #proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:3000";
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

}
```

i have found similar problem solved using htaccess [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630242/redirect-subfolder-to-root-domain)

But how can i achieve in nginx??

Answer (score 1):

One of a number of solutions is:

```
location ^~ /ubb/ {
    return 302 /;
}
```

The `^~` modifier ensures that this *prefix location* continues to take precedence if you were to add any *regex locations* in the future. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

The `return` directive is [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return).